# Header Templates Options

Tags: header

I am trying to create a header template for a GroupBox (for now, and others later on).

Currently I have

```
    <!--GroupBox-->
<Style TargetType="GroupBox">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource wspCharcoalDarkBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource wspTitleBlockBold}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Which works well if I have

```
<GroupBox Margin="3" Header="TEST">
</GroupBox>
```

The Header says "TEST"

If I want to customise it for a one off and use this

```
<GroupBox Margin="3">
    <GroupBox.Header>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image/>
            <TextBlock Text="TEST"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </GroupBox.Header>
</GroupBox>
```

All I get for a header is "System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel" in the header.

Is there a way around this so that I can have the option of specifying the header either way and not have to create 2 separate styles?

Thanks,

Brent